# Forzar una página de error con apache

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd

Me gustaría que cuando se intente acceder a una URL que contenta "wp-" en alguna parte de la URL, apache bloquee esa web. Lo ideal sería que salga un mensaje personalizado, pero no lo he logrado conseguir.

En mi caso he intentado bloquear "wp-admin":

```
<Directory  wp-admin/> 
deny from all 
</Directory>
```

Fichero de configuración de apache (ubuntu): **apache2.conf**

¿Cuál es mi problema?

Realizo la configuración, luego reinicio apache (también intenté detener e iniciar el servicio) y parece que no coge la configuración. A un momento me bloqueaba el "wp-admin", luego quité la configuración, reinicié varias veces y me seguía bloqueando la web. Tuve que eliminar el dominio y volver a instalar WP, ahora es totalmente lo contrario, no me coge la configuración por lo que no bloquea nada.

Reiniciar:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

En primera instancia me gustaría hacer funcionar correctamente esto, luego me gustaría poner un mensaje personalizado, como por ejemplo "No puedes ejecutar WP en este SV".

Algunas fuentes consultadas:

[Apache - Mensaje de error personalizado](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/es/custom-error.html)

Comment: Primero debes saber la [listas de errores http](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) , una vez visto esto, debes agregar a tu virtualhost algo como [`ErrorDocument 403 url_de_permiso_denegado`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/es/mod/core.html#errordocument)

Comment: tené en cuenta que si bloqueas todo el wp-admin estás bloqueando el login, el ajax (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) y los formularios (wp-admin/admin-post.php)

Comment: Si, quiero bloquear todo. NO me funciona :(